# Query Only Works When Using Float Data Type

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, varchar, sqldatatypes

I have a dropdown list populated by this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MR_ID AS INT) AS MR_ID FROM Stage_Rebate_Index";
```

Then I had a table that would display values in a table based on the selection of the dropdown. I used this query to do so. Everything worked!

```
$sql_one = "SELECT CAST(Supp_ID AS INT) AS Supp_ID, CAST(MR_ID AS INT) AS MR_ID FROM Stage_Rebate_Index WHERE MR_ID = '$mr_id'";
```

However, I had to make some changes and this is the query I need to populate my dropdown.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ID_Name, MR_ID as sort_column FROM Stage_Rebate_Index ORDER BY sort_column";
```

And this is the query I use to display the values in a table based on the selection of the dropdown. However, now it doesnt work whatsoever. Anytime a selection is made, the only thing displayed is the table headers. I have figued it out in that the ID_Name column is a varchar while all other columns are the Float data type. Is there anyway to get around this so it works for varchar data types?

```
$sql_one = "
SELECT ID_Name, CAST(Supp_ID as INT) as Supp_ID
FROM Stage_Rebate_Index
WHERE ID_Name = '$mr_id'";
```

Comment: It looks like you went from comparing `$mr_id` to a number (`MR_ID`) to comparing `$mr_id` to a varchar (`ID_Name`). Has the type of value you are passing to `$mr_id` changed? or should you still be comparing `$mr_id` to `MR_ID` or `Supp_ID`?

Comment: `$mr_id` will need to be equal to the value selected in the dropdown `ID_Name` which is a varchar

Comment: Since you didn't provide any example data: is it possible, that you have leading zeros in the name? These would be cut away in the int... so you would compare "01" against "1", which is false... However: could you provide some example of your first and second query please?

Comment: There are no zeros...the old query would just be getting and displaying numbers while the new query pulls from the ID_Name column, which is the MR_ID concatted with a company name, so for example, it would look like "1 - Company A", "2 - Company B", etc.

Comment: `WHERE ID_Name = '$mr_id'" ` Why ID_Name should equals MR_ID?